# difference between IoT Foundation and Node-RED?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

We have 2 boilerplates with Node-RED in Bluemix catalogs.

I know that the Node-RED Starter boilerplate has the Monitoring and Analytics service.

Is this the only difference?

Are there any differences between "IoT Foundation Starter" and "Node-RED Starter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IoT Foundation Starter` comes with a flow pre-deployed to demonstrate using the IoT Foundation service.

The `Node-RED` boiler plate comes with no flow deployed so you have a blank canvas to work from.